# add id dynamically to jquery tabs

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, tabs, jquery-ui-tabs, jquery-tabs

I am creating jquery tabs dynamically. I want to associate the the id to each tab.

```
$(function() {
    var index = 0;
    $("#addTab").live('click', function() {
        index++;
        var title = 'Tab.....  ' + index;
        var url = '#fragment-' + index;

        addTab(url, title, index);
        $('li.ui-state-default').attr("id",index);
});
```

This code successfully assigns the id. But when I create a new tab. It assigns the id to whole class. I didn't want to do this. I just want to assign the unique id to each class

JS Fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/gP3YZ/9/

Comment: Sounds like something you should do **inside** your `addTab()` function, rather than here.

Comment: `addTab()` is **not** a jQuery function. What I meant was that, since it's `addTab()` that's creating the new dynamic tabs, why not put the logic to add the `id` there as well? Instead of doing that *after* `addTab()` returns.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('li.ui-state-default:last').attr("id",index).attr('id');
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/thecodeparadox/DsA8T/)**

Answer (score 4):

```
$('li.ui-state-default').each( function(){
    $(this).attr("id",index++);
});
```

By the way, it's bad practice to use numbers as DOM Element's id, use something like `("item-"+index)` as `id` attribute.